# Pandas to check if value is NONE

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'k':['a','b','c'],'v':[1,None,3]})

   k    v
0  a  1.0
1  b  NaN
2  c  3.0
```

I want to check if column `k`'s `b` value is NaN or not

I have tried

```
if df['v'][df['k']=='b'] is None:
    print("yes")
else:
    print('no')
```

this gives output no

I have also tried

```
if df['v'][df['k']=='b'] == None:
    print("yes")
else:
    print('no')
```

and

```
if df['v'][df['k']=='b'].isna():
    print("yes")
else:
    print('no')
```

both give me this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as long a you have a null value, you would want to return the `True` then use `.any()`. If you want all values to be Null (in this case it doesn't matter because there's a single value) then use `.all()`:

```
if df[df['k']=='b']['v'].isna().any():
    print("yes")
else:
    print('no')
```

Output:

`yes`